# Can't upload files to local directory

Tags: forms, scala, file-upload, playframework

I can't seem to upload files to my local directory, placing them in the appdata/Temp directory works but its only temporarily, which is why I want to upload them to a directory other than Temp

I've tried following a couple tutorials but I seem to get the same error:

```
[NoSuchFileException: C:\*****\multipartBody2177348957005612751asTemporaryFile -> \*****\Knipsel.PNG]
```

views.html.index:

```
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.uploadFile, 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {
< input type="file" name="fileUpload">
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</p>
}
```

Application.scala

```
 import java.io.File

 def uploadFile = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
 request.body.file("fileUpload").map { picture =>
  val Filename = picture.filename
  val contentType = picture.contentType.get
  picture.ref.moveTo(new File("/*****/" + picture.filename))
}.getOrElse {
  Redirect(routes.Application.index)
}
Ok("File has been uploaded")
}
```

routes:

```
POST    /upload                 controllers.Application.uploadFile
```

tutorials:

http://blog.knoldus.com/2013/01/22/play-framework-uploading-a-file-to-server/

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaFileUpload

I hope that this is enough information to help me, thanks in advance

P.S. I'm using IntelliJ 15.0 if that makes any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are running this tutorial from a Windows machine so I would change the line:

```
picture.ref.moveTo(new File("/*****/" + picture.filename))
```

to this:

```
picture.ref.moveTo(new File("""C:\*****\""" + picture.filename))
```

Comment: If you don't like the '\\' slash escaped, there is always the """""". I'll update the answer according.